# Would like to create conditional intervals off character time using R

Tags: r, datetime, conditional-statements

I have a list of time

```
 df$Interval = cut(as.POSIXct(df$time1,format="%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01"), 
                breaks=as.POSIXct(c("2021-03-25 00:00:00","2021-03-25 07:59:59",
                                    "2021-03-25 15:59:59","2021-03-25 23:59:59"), tz="UTC"),
                labels=c("First Tour","Second Tour","Third Tour"))
```

I have a column of time

```
        time1|
    "05:06:00"
    "23:10:00"
    "04:05:00"
    "22:12:00"
    "09:06:12"
```

The script works but i have to keep changing the date every day because

```
  as.POSIXct(df$time1,format="%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01")
```

turns the time into

```
        time1|
    "2021-03-26 05:06:00 UTC"
    "2021-03-26 23:10:00 UTC"
    "2021-03-26 04:05:00 UTC"
    "2021-03-26 22:12:00 UTC"
    "2021-03-26 09:06:12 UTC"
```

So either solution is fine. Is there a way to run an interval with just time in "%H:%M:%S and i don't have to worry about date, or is there a way to add a standard date that would just be the same regardless of date for example

```
             time1|
    "1990-01-01 05:06:00 UTC"
    "1990-01-01 23:10:00 UTC"
    "1990-01-01 04:05:00 UTC"
    "1990-01-01 22:12:00 UTC"
    "1990-01-01 09:06:12 UTC"
```

Ultimately my result should be

```
        time1|time interval
    "05:06:00" first tour
    "23:10:00" third tour
    "04:05:00" first tour
    "22:12:00" second tour
    "09:06:12" third tour
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using date-time classes, so switch to time objects with `chron::times`

```
time1 <- c(
  "05:06:00"
  , "23:10:00"
  , "04:05:00"
  , "22:12:00"
  , "09:06:12"
)

df <- data.frame(time1=time1)

df$time_interval <- cut(chron::times(df$time1), 
    breaks=chron::times(c(
      "00:00:00"
      ,"07:59:59"
      ,"15:59:59"
      ,"23:59:59")
    )
    , labels=c(
      "First Tour"
      ,"Second Tour"
      ,"Third Tour")
)
  
> df
     time1 time_interval
1 05:06:00    First Tour
2 23:10:00    Third Tour
3 04:05:00    First Tour
4 22:12:00    Third Tour
5 09:06:12   Second Tour
```

HTH